# Load all css and Js files starting with name main.*.css and main.*.js

Tags: javascript, css, html, reactjs

In my index.html , i want to load all css and js files matching certain pattern.

```
<link href="https://abc.xyz.com/static/css/main.*.css">
<script src="https://abc.xyz.com/static/js/main.*.js"></script>
```

eg- all files which matches name main.abc.css , main.788.css and main.abc.js and main.6788.js

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do that, but you could use a bundler such as webpack.

Comment: why don't you load each file one by one?

Comment: You would have to make the server list, what files actually are in the directory. You could then load them dynamically with JavaScript. However you can't just make a script or even a wildcard in HTML, because this will always run client side and, if not explicitly configured, the webserver won't show what files are in your js and css directories. You then would have to "brute-force" the correct filenames and check if they exist.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be achieved straight forward. As you can see, the value of the href attribute is a string. The browser would read the whole string as is.

In order to do this, you'll have to work with how you package your JS/CSS files.

Option 1 : You can use a bundler like webpack to package the files as you require into separate JS/CSS files, based on the patterns you want to use.

Option 2 : Use a server side script. You can get the list of files in the path, iterate over them and include the ones you want to. This is not recommended though. It is always safer to include only those files that you want to include